# A better way to not use dockerhub - permanent config within docker?

Tags: docker, artifactory, dockerhub

I've searched the documentation for docker if this is possible and come up blank, but thought I'd pose the question here before shelving this.
Is there a way to just tell Docker to use something other than dockerhub as a first port of call?

We're using Artifactory's virtual repository to merge local and remote repositories into one convenient output, but my main gripe is having to say `docker pull docker-virtual-stage.artifactory.mycompany.com/centos` instead of just `docker pull centos`.

Jfrogs method to get this endpoint seems over-complex \ not easily scaled up.

TL;DR: Is there a better way to not use dockerhub while remaining user friendly?

Comment: It doesn't appear that changing the default registry is going to be supported: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/7203

Comment: @swysocki it's a shame. I'd even consider it counter productive, but as docker is so established, I imagine they don't see a need to be more open...

Answer (score 1):

How about setting the registry mirror, and then blocking blocking DNS to docker.io just to make sure it goes to your mirror?

```
#/etc/docker/daemon.json

{
"registry-mirrors": ["https://docker-virtual-stage.artifactory.mycompany.com"]
}
```

As this guy suggested:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/64158584/10664600